# How do we create selenium webdriver objects within a loop and close the window once the loop ends?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sleep

So I'm trying to open each link in a list (which is run through by a for loop) and perform some operations on that link.

I want to open a window for each link in the loop, operate on it, close it and then start the loop over.

```
for link in links_list:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/location-of-driver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    driver.get(link)

    a_variable = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('selector')

    time.sleep(3)  # required for my usage

    driver.close()  # this I believe should close the window
```

So the loop iterates 1 time and crashes when it reaches the top again. driver.close() works for the first iteration

I would want the window with the current link to be open for 3 seconds and the loop to start over.

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./play.py", line 18, in <module>
    driver.get(link)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 
(ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 
x86_64)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code looks fine.I have tested.One thing can you do to update selenium. pip install -U selenium

Comment: I'm on 3.141.0 itself :(

Comment: Ok,Can you please share ur link list if possible

Comment: So I tried to not close the window altogether and the code works, when we remove driver.close()

The link list was just a list of SoundCloud song URLs

Comment: But tried your code with my link list and it worked.If you wish I can share you the code just test and check whether it gives problem

Comment: Sure thing, post it

Comment: ok.I'll post it as another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gaurav as discussed please try this.If you get similar problem then i believe you have update chrome driver to latest one.

```
links_list = ["https://www.google.com/", "https://www.w3schools.com/","https://www.toolsqa.com/"]

for link in links_list:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Java/TestChrome/lib/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    print(link)
    driver.get(link)

   # a_variable = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('selector')

    time.sleep(3)  # required for my usage

    #driver.quit()  # this I believe should close the window
    driver.close()

print('pass')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.quit()
```

This is used to quit the driver and close every associated window.

```
driver.close()
```

This is used to close the current window.

Your error comes from trying to close a window when the driver has already been quit.

**Solution**

Use only the `close` method, you do not have to use `quit` for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks! Immediately after posting this question I realised that mistake of mine haha. I've updated the question with the errors I'm still facing.

Comment: Hehe. Alright. Trying to see what is wrong with the new code.

Comment: @GauravK Is there any specific reason you need to close the window? You could just load the new link in that same window. I'm asking because you would have to wait for each loop to end before loading each link.

Comment: So I'm opening a SoundCloud page and SoundCloud automatically plays the audio when a new window is opened. 

I did try not closing the window, the code works without the need for driver.close()

Comment: This is a more appropriate answer. I was running driver.get(newPage) and driver.quit() in loops and it was crashing after the first iteration. It ought to be driver.close(). It works like a charm now.